# translate angular pagination text ( previous - next )

Tags: angular, text, pagination, angular6, translate

I have an app on angular 6 , who i can change the text (previous and next) on my pagination table?
im ussing "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
i have this and its works ok but the 'previousPage' doesnt change, the rest its ok

```
"let s of datos | paginate : { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage : pageActual, previousPage: 'something' }"

<< Previous 1 2 3 Next >>
```

i want change languaje like this

```
 << something text  1 2 3 another text >>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom translation pipe which uses a dictionary created by you to replace corresponding word with the key you provide.

I've prepared a small POC for you in StackBlitz, check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmnaw3).